# Sort list of Objects react-native by value not key

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, jsx

I have problems to sort a list of objects in React-native by a time value. I can't find the answer online. Do you have any suggestions?

My console log in chrome of original object:
[image: My console log in chrome of original object]

Firebase database structure

[image: Firebase database structure]

JSON.stringify(myObject) output:

```
myObject={"-LAqmXKSdVVH6wirFa-g": 
{"desc":"fdf","price":"rrrr","receiveHelp":true,"subject":"Single Variable 
Calculus","time":1524558865757,"title":"Test1"},"-LAqmZlBFGoygfTsGQ0e": 
{"desc":"dsfdsfd3","price":"333","receiveHelp":true,"subject":"Single 
Variable Calculus","time":1524558875724,"title":"Test2"},"- 
LAqmcipUjlwLWTrRCw4": 
{"desc":"werwerwe55","price":"44","receiveHelp":true,"subject":"Single 
Variable Calculus","time":1524558891956,"title":"Test3"},"- 
LArMeYfHG6QMg_Frn9A": 
{"desc":"3","price":"3","receiveHelp":true,"subject":"Single Variable 
Calculus","time":1524568598762,"title":"Annons 1"},"-LArMjg5MkF5cMPZd_Fz": 
{"desc":"2222","price":"2","receiveHelp":true,"subject":"Single Variable 
 Calculus","time":1524568619782,"title":"Annons2"},"-LArNM-3Ij60XmSOBwvr": 
{"desc":"22","price":"","receiveHelp":true,"subject":"Single Variable 
 Calculus","time":1524568780803,"title":"Hej1"},"-LArNPugIfX1pPVZJ11e": 
{"desc":"f","price":"2","receiveHelp":true,"subject":"Single Variable 
 Calculus","time":1524568796844,"title":"Hej2f"}}
```

What I have tried so far:

```
firebase.database().ref('/users').once('value').then((snapshot) => {
const ads = snapshot.val();
let myObject = {};
Object.keys(ads).map((objectKey) => {
  const value = ads[objectKey];
  myObject = Object.assign(value.ads, myObject);
});

//Here i want to sort myObject by time and get the latest first

console.log(myObject)
```

Comment: You should include your object structures and data in this post, not as external links.

Comment: Your data has multiple level, so at which level do you want to sort. You question does not explain well

Comment: i've printed the JSON.stringify(myObject) output, so it is this output i want to sort

Comment: You are overriding `myObject` value in each iteration so how you will get an array or collection.

Comment: How should i do instead of overriding myObject to collect all users ads? And then sort?

Comment: @gynther I've updated my answer. Have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to combine ads or all users into one array and then sort

```js
let sortedAdds = Object.keys(usersData)
.reduce((prev, userId) => {
 let ads = usersData[userId].ads;
  ads = Object.keys(ads).map(key => {
     return { ...ads[key], id: key };
  });
  return prev.concat(ads);
}, [])
.sort((a, b) => (a.time - b.time));
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't sort. Is this correct?

const arrayData = Object.keys(myObject).map(key => {
  const obj = { ...myObject[key] };
  obj.id = key;
  return obj;
}).sort((a, b) => {
  return a.time - b.time;
});
    console.log(arrayData);

Comment: Can you update your question with partial stringified value of `myObject`  like `JSON.stringify(myObject)`

Answer (score 1):

```
([obj1, obj2]).sort((tm1, tm2) => {
  if (tm1.time > tm2.time) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (tm1.time < tm2.time) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
})
```

Comment: how do I apply this to myObject?

Comment: Are you trying to return a new object or an array? Use `Object.keys(myObject)` which will give you an array. If you need a new object you'll need to call `reduce` on that array.

Comment: So first Object.keys(myObject) . Then (myObject.sort((tm1, tm2) => { .... ?

Comment: Do `Object.keys(myObject).sort(...`

Answer (score 0):

You could, instead of sorting in your front-end, use the sorting capabilities of the Firebase database by doing:

```
var ref = database.ref('users/' + adId + '/ads').orderByChild('time');
```

If you then loop over the results of this query, the ads will be ordered according to the time

```
ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        console.log(childData);
    });
});
```

Edit: if you want to have the "latest gets first" which I understand as "the most recent should be the first", you should then store the `time*(-1)` instead of `time` (`time` being the milliseconds since the unix epoch, as show in your question)

Comment: What I refered as adId is actually the Id of the parent of the set of ads, i.e. mRVppiPwL1.... in your image. You should know it normally since you are querying a set of its children